# Wordpress display read more in the entry footer

Tags: php, wordpress

here is what I want to do:

I have a blog post which I want to display only to a specific point. So in the post I put

```
<!--more-->
```

on the right position.

My content.php looks like this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content('read more'); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php mytheme_entry_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

The "read more" link gets displayed right after the content where it should be. But how can I display it inside the entry footer with the "Comment" link?

Is there a solution with the excerpt?

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

I think this would even be better because I wouldnt need to put the  line in every post.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the 'read more' by using the following filter in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link', 10, 2 );

function remove_more_link( $more_link, $more_link_text ) {
    return;
}
```

Now you can create your own read more link inside entry-footer:

```
<footer class="entry-footer">
    <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
    <?php mytheme_entry_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

Edit:

In comments below the following question was asked:

> I used the_excerpt() instead of the_content(). Is it possible to only display the link if the post is actually too long?

You can do this by checking if the excerpt is different from the content. If this is the case (so there is more content than the excerpt is showing) you can show the read more link:

```
<?php if ( get_the_content() != get_the_excerpt() ){ ?>

    <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That works fine for me. I used the_excerpt() instead of the_content().
Is it possible to only display the link if the post is actually too long? (more than 55 chars)

Comment: @HansUllrich maybe you can check if (the length of) the excerpt ( `get_the_excerpt()` ) is equal to (the length of) the content ( `get_the_content()` ). If they are different you can show the read more link.

Comment: ok if I make the condition get_the_excerpt() < get_the_content() it always displays the link. The other way around it doesn't display the link. If I ask if they are equal I get the following error:

"Can't use function return value in write context"

Comment: @HansUllrich just added an example to my answer. Just tested this and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I use one workaround:

```
//REMOVE 'MORE' LINK AND HARDCODE IT INTO PAGE - TEASER JUST PLAIN ELLIPSIS
function modify_read_more_link() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        return '...';
    } else {
        return '</div><footer class="clearfix"><a class="mg-read-more" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Continue Reading <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>';
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

Explanation: for front page I have a short overview only clickable in the post title. And for blog list (after `else` in the above `function.php` ):

```html
<article>
  <header></header>
  <div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </footer>
</article>
```

In which you can notice missing `div` closing and `footer` opening tags. It is a bit messi, but it brings the original Wordpress Teaser into next division.

Thankyou for reading.